# Is this curve known?

Tags: plane-curves

A median of a triangle through mid-point of $(-c,0),(c,0) $ is such so that ratio of cosines of angles between sides/median

$$ \cos \phi/\cos \psi =e $$  is a constant. Is the curve known?

$$ \frac {((x + c) x + y^2)}{((x - c) x + y^2)} \,
  \sqrt{ \frac{((x - c) ^2 + y^2}{((x + c) ^2 + y^2}} = e $$

[image: Apollonius Circle Types]

Seems to be a fourth order curve:

Comment: It doesn't appear as a known curve. It can somewhat be considered as a "generalized conic" : see the article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_conic)

Comment: Thanks. Actually  I was playing with variants of the Apollonius Circle .. no luck in its generalization..

Comment: The curve  is symmetriic  wrt x- and y- axes.